# Numeric solvers for stochastic differential equations in R: are there any?

Tags: r, simulation, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I'm looking for a general, clean and fast (i.e. using C++ routines) R package for simulating paths from a non-homogeneous nonlinear diffusion like (1) using the Euler-Maruyama scheme, the Milstein scheme (or any other). This is destined to be embedded into a larger estimation code and therefore deserves to be optimized.

$$dX_t = f(\theta, t, X_t)\, dt + g(\theta, t, X_t)\, dW_t, \tag{1}$$

with $W_t$ the standard Brownian motion.

Comment: (+1) Interesting question. It is important to notice that the solution to this sort of SDE [does not always exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions) or it may not be unique. In addition, simulation of [diffusion processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_process) can be quite difficult (it is actually a hot topic at the moment).

Comment: It is. Analytic solutions are indeed rare and the existence of a solution is to be demonstrated but you are always able to simulate though...I will end-up recoding my R programs in C if nobody comes up with a ready made tool...most general analysis software generally have an all-purpose solver funny R seems to provide only specific simulators, or I may have overlooked the right package

Comment: Here is a good place (and people) to start with: http://web.warwick.ac.uk/statsdept/user-2011/tutorials/Soetaert.html

Answer (score 7):

CRAN is your friend: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html

#### Stochastic Differential Equations (SDEs)

In a stochastic differential equation, the unknown quantity is a stochastic process.

- The package `sde` provides functions for simulation and inference for stochastic differential equations. It is the accompanying package to the book by Iacus (2008).
- The package `pomp` contains functions for statistical inference for partially observed Markov processes.
- The `Sim.DiffProc` package simulates diffusion processes and has functions for numerical solution of stochastic differential equations.
- Package `GillespieSSA` implements Gillespie's exact stochastic simulation algorithm (Direct method) and several approximate methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a R package for SDE: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sde/sde.pdf
But I am not sure if it works for non-homogeneous SDE