# Stochastic Volatility and SDEs

Tags: r, simulation, stochastic-processes

Consider the following SDEs 
$$\begin{align}
&\dfrac{\text{d}S}{S}(t) = \alpha(t)\text{ d}t + \sigma(t)\text{ d}Z^{(1)}(t) \\
&\dfrac{\text{d}\sigma}{\sigma}(t) = \beta(t)\text{ d}t + \gamma(t)\text{ d}Z^{(2)}(t)
\end{align}$$
with the stochastic volatility term.

I've already seen [Numeric solvers for stochastic differential equations in R: are there any?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38756/numeric-solvers-for-stochastic-differential-equations-in-r-are-there-any), but have not seen anything very helpful for simulating $S$ with the stochastic volatility, as above.

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: Can you specify the form of the SDE? I am not aware of general methods to solve SDE's woith stochastic volatility, especially not for the multivariate case. One specific implemetation for the univariate case would be for example the     stochvol    package in R, however, this implies certain restrictions on the choice of the parameters.

Comment: @muffin1974 Sorry, can't edit the previous post $$\begin{align}
\text{d}\sigma(t) &= \kappa(\theta - \sigma(t))\text{ d}t + \tau\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\text{ d}Z^{(1)}(t) \\
\text{d}S(t) &= \mu S(t)\text{ d}t + S(t)\sqrt{\sigma(t)}\left(\rho \text{d}Z^{(1)}(t) + \sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}\text{ d}Z^{(2)}(t)\right)
\end{align}$$